# How to update an SQL database with form data using PHP?

Tags: php, html, sql

How do I get html form POST data to appear after the = signs?

```
$tsql = "UPDATE dbo.[order] 
 SET status=''
 WHERE order_ID='' ";
```

Comment: Learn basic PHP, perhaps? http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: Be careful out there; http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: ......perhaps is a great word.

Comment: I'm trying.  Sorry about the dumb question :)

Comment: @Alex_TCD no question is a dumb question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All POST data is stored in `$_POST`
put $_POST['dataname'] there.

```
SET status='".$_POST['dataname']."'
```

would be the proper replacement.

Comment: Like this? $tsql = "UPDATE dbo.[order] 
  SET status='".$_POST['status']."'
  WHERE order_ID='".$_POST['order_ID']."'";

Comment: If those are the fields from the HTML, yes

Comment: Thanks Forbs.  This worked.  It's just an intranet project with a few employees so I didn't feel the need to sanitize it.

Answer (score 1):

POST data can be retrieved using the $_POST suberglobal like this:

```
.... " SET status = '{$_POST['form_field_name']}'";
```

HOWEVER, I would recommend using prepared statements for this whenever possible. Putting form data directly into an SQL statement is a bad practice and can cause security issues.

You should use a prepared statement like this:

```
// Store the form data in variables
$status = $_POST['status_field'];
$order_ID = $_POST['order_ID_field'];

// If you're not going to use prepared statements AT LEAST do this
// Not a necessary step if using prepared statements
$sanitized_status = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnection, $status);
$sanitized_order_ID = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnection, $order_ID);

// Prepare the SQL 
// When script is run database will compile this statement first
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('UPDATE table_name SET status = ? WHERE order_ID = ?');
// Parameters are bound to the COMPILED statement not the string
$stmt->bind_param('si', $sanitized_status, $sanitized_order_ID);

$stmt->execute();
```

The key is to bind your form data to the compiled statement and not the SQL string itself. Read more about prepared statements in this excellent resource below!

**Reference:** [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)